# Adding php page to drupal7

Tags: php, drupal

I have googled my question many times but i cant find a good solution. I want to add a php page into drupal.

Is there a way to call(perhaps a menu link) a php page within the existing drupal(template) with an include or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From http://drupal.org/node/1046700

> Drupal 7 Core contains a module called "PHP filter". A fresh install
>   of Drupal 7 has this module disabled by default. We need to enable it.

Any page or block text area can include PHP code in drupal, if the PHP filter is enabled and the user has permission to use it.

If you want to add a link to a PHP file completely outside of the drupal CMS, you can do so too.

example)

```
<a href="http://yoursite.com/your/physical/path/to/a/php/file.php">  
    external PHP file  
</a>
```

Comment: Even though the PHP filter module is part of Drupal core, it's generally a bad idea to use it. It means you're storing your php code in the database instead of files, which is less maintainable, less secure and bad for performance. The PHP filter module will likely be removed from the next Drupal version. If you want to run your own php script within a Drupal site, you can write a simple custom module.

Comment: Ive tried to use the php filter and it works great.
But when i have attached some css to the php file the markup is not correct i gues theres no solution for this. So i have to try to develop a module in drupal

Comment: @DownDown are you using http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/7?

Answer (score 0):

unable to understand the question completely ... is the PHP page to be used within a module?? perhaps use 'file' and 'file path' in the hook_menu of your module to include the page .... or if its in block level would suggest the previous answer from @DownDown ....